# click on link in email to populate textfield

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

I need to populate a textfield when a user clicks on a link. I have successfully done this with javascript, but the link now needs to be in a HTML email and most email software disregards javascript.

Any other way?

What I need id for the user to click on 'Make an enquiry' in my HTML email which links to my homepage, where a textfield will be populated with a code, for example 'email_offer_1'

Comment: Does your landing page use any server-side languages, e.g. PHP, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the relevant information to the HTML page via the hash, or via the query string [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#section_5)

So the link in the e-mail may say `<a href="mysite.com/inquiry#_56">Inquiries Here</a>`, and then the HTML page can be set up to check it's hash for information on ready.